# How come in Chrome or Firefox's debugger, no :focus or :hover style is shown and not even in the computed value of CSS?

Tags: css, debugging

Let's say if we go to [Bootstrap's pagination section](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination) and moved that sample into our sample page, with no JavaScript whatsoever.

I think the "hover" and get grey background effect, as well as the "click" and grey background effect, is done by something like this, which I add to my page as well:

```
    .pagination li a:focus { background: #fa6 !important }
    .pagination li a:hover { background: #fa6 !important }
```

However, I don't know why when I inspect that `<a>` element on Google Chrome or Firefox's debugger, I do not see the CSS rule come into view, and also, I do not see the "computed value" of CSS showing a different value -- all it shows is `#ffffff` for white.

I thought I did see the `:hover` or `:focus` being listed in the CSS rules before (and the computed value will change as well in the past).  What is happening and can we see that as before?

Comment: The computed value isn't going to be #fa6 if the element is neither being focused nor hovered.

Comment: @BoltClock what I mean is, when it is hovered or focused, I still don't see it

Comment: Could you paste the selector that is giving the white background? Maybe is a simple specificity question and you have tired eyes. (or some kind of typo)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap specifically target `a` to design it. You have to override the bootstrap by this way-

```
.pagination>li>a:focus,
.pagination>li>a:hover, 
.pagination>li>span:focus, 
.pagination>li>span:hover
{
    background: #fa6    
}
```

Comment: I was able to override it, as shown on my sample page. Just that I don't see the CSS rule showing up and no new computed value showed

Comment: have you changed the state while using Chrome developer tool ? What I mean is http://i.imgur.com/WR4vIzN.png?1

Comment: I did not force it.  I only hover over it or "focused it", and so on the page, I do see the background change, but the computed value doesn't change